# Зависает exe после компиляции С#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, компиляция, exe

Всем привет. Сегодня впервые столкнулся с проблемой, и не могу понять, в чем дело.
В Visual Studio 2015 скомпилил программу, все запускается нормально. Но из папки проекта - никак. Тупо висит в процессах. Пробовал менять версии .net, менять разрядность систем для запуска - 0 эмоций. Просто висит в процессах и все. При запуске (на F5) из среды - запускается и работает отлично. В чем может быть проблема? Может, сталкивался кто? Заранее спасибо.

P.S - все библиотеки стандартные, новых не подключал.

Comment: Антивирус не AVAST часом?

Comment: Владимир Мартьянов, спасибо! Вот как так? Отрубил, все пошло. Раньше таких проблем с ним не было, потому и не грешил на него. Спасибо огромное.

Comment: Не знаю как так, но проблема частая. Я бы руки за такое им поотрывал. Попробуйте авастам написать, может ответят в чем именно проблема, но что-то сомневаюсь...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если антивирус AVAST - пробуйте отключить или занести каталог с файлом в исключения.

Comment: А лучше вообще удалить, антивирус программисту десктопа - как адблок фронтендеру.

Comment: @FLCL в общем случае зачем? Тут корявый АВ, который не выдает уведомлений при обнаружении угрозы и реакции по ней. Если АВ четко говорит "нашел, заблокировал" - хотя бы понятно где проблема.

Comment: Отличный совет, без сарказма :) Только о юзерах тоже думать надо. У них же и адблок стоит, и аваст

Comment: Блокировка "белого кода" антивирусом - проблема исключительно антивируса. Последнее время аверы ведут себя слишком параноидально.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов программирование - дело информационно насыщенное, надо знать как работают фреймворки, среды и прочие инструменты. Анивирусы - ещё одна вещь которая влияет на систему, со своими багами и пробелами в интерфейсе. Порт не открылся, программа не самомодифицируется как задумано или чек суммы не совпадают, меня хватило на полгода, когда я начал писать для системы. А для проверки взаимодействия с антивирусами и адблоком должна быть отдельная тестовая среда.