# Не запускаются программы, скомплилированные под Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Программы, скомпилированные под Visual Studio не запускаются. В общем, делал проект C++ в VS 2010 на Windows 7 с .NET Framework 4.6.1. Получилось так, что теперь работаю на другом компьютере с Windows 10. Здесь у меня VS 2015 Community, .NET Framework 4.6.1. точно так же. Проект, который сохранял в 2010 на винде 7 добавил в 2015, компилирую, всё нормально. А когда запускаю решение, то зависает IDE и курсор становится в позицию загрузки и постоянно крутится, но ничего не запускается. Если запускать сам exe из папки, точно так же, только зависает уже explorer.exe и приходится убивать его в процессах. Пробовал делать другой проект С++ в 2015, тупо привет мир, тоже самое. Но как ни странно другие exe в системе запускаются, в т.ч. скомплилированные из под CodeBlocks с MinGW.

Что делать? Не могу найти решение, а мне надо работать с проектом в VS, потому что тут отладчик нормальный.

**updt:** 
прога скопмиленая под VC не запускается, даже примитивная. ТЫкаешь - ничего не происходит, курсор меняется на ожидание -типа когда прога подвисает, и все. в диспетчере задач нет программы, курсор висит всегда если в папку где exe лежит зайти, помогает только перезагрузка.
проверяли на вин 8.1 у меня сначала, не работало, потом еще у человека на такой же win 8.1, не работало. На семерке работает, у знакомой на 10-ке запускается. Обновил 8.1 до 10, думал, что исправит проблему, не помогло...

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472861/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-exe-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%A1/472862 не оно ли?

Comment: немного отличается, но спасибо, сейчас что-нибудь из этого попробую, но аваст уже пробовали отключать, никаких изменений

Comment: То есть Аваст все-таки стоит? Попробуйте его совсем отключить, чтобы никакие компоненты не работали...

Comment: Да, всё решилось похоже, это аваст. Добавил в нем исключение папки, где лежит проект и всё стало запускаться. Какой-то странный аваст. Кошмар, два дня мучался

Comment: Тогда закрывайте как копию.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, хоть я мучился два дня, пытаясь понять, почему не запускаются exe из под Visual Studio, а знакомый вообще неделю мучился, проблему решил через 5 минут после добавления вопроса. В общем, проблема была в антивирусе. У нас у обоих стоял Avast. Мы добавили папку с проектом в исключения в настройках Avast(настройки/активная защита/экран файловой системы  -> добавить исключение - путь к папке с проектом, ну или как там решите). В общем, думаю, что кому-нибудь может пригодиться.
Судя по всему, Avast сидит на довольно глубоком системном уровне и ничего не удается запустить, так как он до запуска начинает как-то файл анализировать, гонять там его и память не заюзать, в общем как-то так.

Comment: Любой "приличный" АВ должен иметь кернелмодный компонент, который позволит ему быть в курсе всех файловых операций.