# Программа работает исключительно при запуске из Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, build, dump

По факту если запускать из вижуалки -- все работает прекрасно.

- Если попробовать запустить екзешник с папки дебаг
- если запустить екзешник с папки релиз
- если запустить заПаблишеный сетап

-- одно и то же поведение. Запускается апликуха, но вот в таком-вот виде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть 42-64к размером(что, конечно же, ненормально), не убиваемый процесс и невозможно снять дамп.

Кто сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472861/Зависает-exe-после-компиляции-С/472862 не оно?

Comment: Да, очень похоже. Тем более что там аваст стоит. Я попробую. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в Avast Antivirus.

Решение взято с [Зависает exe после компиляции С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472861/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-exe-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%A1/472862)

по коментарию @Владимир Мартьянов
Спасибо большое